# How to make a shape outside of the main() function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fltk

I know how to define a shape (here, a rectangle) and attach it to a window in C++ as follows:

```
  #include <Simple_window.h>

void cir() { Circle c(Point(100,100),50); }

int main()
{
  Simple_window win(Point(100,100),600,400, "test");

  Rectangle r(Point(100,100),Point(300,200));
  win.attach(r);
  win.wait_for_botton();

}
```

But how to define a shape (say a `circle` by that `cir()` function which is) outside of the `main()`
function that is how to create a circle inside of the cir() function and it returns that circle when I called it in my main() function so that I can attach it on the window `win` to be visible?

PS: I have learned C++ just by PPP book ([this](http://books.google.com/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=programming%20principle%20and%20practice&pg=PA519#v=onepage&q&f=true)) and only until end of chapter 14 :-)

Comment: you could pass by reference the `win` variable to the `cir` method and attach the circle inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
  #include <Simple_window.h>

  Circle c(Point(100,100),50);

  int main()
  {
    Simple_window win(Point(100,100),600,400, "test");

    Rectangle r(Point(100,100),Point(300,200));
    win.attach(r);
    win.attach(c);
    win.wait_for_botton();
  }
```

or, if you want to use your cir function:

```
Circle cir()
{
  Circle c(Point(100,100),50);
  return c;
}

int main()
{
  Simple_window win(Point(100,100),600,400, "test");

  Rectangle r(Point(100,100),Point(300,200));
  win.attach(r);
  win.attach(cir());
  win.wait_for_botton();
}
```

Or perhaps you wanted to do something like this, it's hard to know from your question:

```
// The & is important, it will pass this argument as a reference
void attachCircleToWindow(Simple_window &win) 
{
  Circle c(Point(100,100),50);
  win.attach(c);
}

int main()
{
  Simple_window win(Point(100,100),600,400, "test");

  Rectangle r(Point(100,100),Point(300,200));
  win.attach(r);
  attachCircleToWindow(win);
  win.wait_for_botton();
}
```

Comment: `cir()` has a void return type. `win.attach(cir());` would be an error.

Comment: Right you are, Josh. Expanded my answer.

Comment: I tried something just like your last code but got many errors!

Comment: For your second code I got this errer _Error 8 error C2248: 'Graph_lib::Shape::Shape' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Graph_lib::Shape' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\graph.h 290_ and for the third I got [this errors](http://tinypic.com/r/6rsv9t/8).

Comment: Isn't there any way!?